# I cannot update my oracle database using c#

Tags: c#, oracle, ora-00933

I'm trying to update my oracle database from c# but I get this error

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

and I don't know what to do.

```
String sqlCommand = "UPDATE CLIENTI_CD ";
sqlCommand += "set nume_client=" + txtNumeC.Text+ "'";
sqlCommand += ",localit_client="+txtLocalitateC.Text+ "'";
sqlCommand +=",data_n to_date('"+txtDataN.Text+"','DDMMYYYY')";
sqlCommand += "where cod_client=" + label1.Text;
```

Comment: Try adding a space after the paren on line 4 or before "where" on line 5. Also, I don't know where your data is coming from, but it appears to be open to SQL injection if you're just feeding directly from textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate causes of the exception are:

omitted `"'"`s:

```
  sqlCommand += "set nume_client='" + txtNumeC.Text + "'";
  sqlCommand += ",localit_client='" + txtLocalitateC.Text + "'";
```

omitted `"="`:

```
  sqlCommand +=",data_n = to_date('" + txtDataN.Text+"','DDMMYYYY')"; // please, notice "="
```

The best way, however, is to use *parametrized* query:

```
  String sqlCommand = 
    @"update CLIENTI_CD
         set nume_client = :prm_nume_client,
             localit_client = :prm_localit_client,
             data_n = to_date(:prm_date, 'DDMMYYYY')
       where cod_client = :prm_cod_client";
```

when you can't/don't want to put parametrized query, use at least a *formatted* one

```
  String sqlCommand = String.Format(
     @"update CLIENTI_CD
          set nume_client = '{0}',
              localit_client = '{1}',
              data_n = to_date('{2}', 'DDMMYYYY')
        where cod_client = {3}",
    txtNumeC.Text, 
    txtLocalitateC.Text, 
    txtDataN.Text, 
    label1.Text);
```

Comment: @Catalin Duceac: then you have to *debug*: what is the `sqlCommand` string before executing?

Comment: Now I'm getting "ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated"

Comment: @Catalin Duceac: I see. Have a look at my edit, you've got yet another syntax error

Comment: When debugging a sql command, it is helpful to look at the query as a complete string before it is executed against the database.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks a bunch:)